# Javascript load external script when htmlElement <script> is created

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem when i am trying to load an external js and run a function inside once the script tag is created. In myFile.js code i have this code :

```
function loadMyScript() {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
var s;
s = document.createElement("script");
s.defer = true;
s.id = "test";
s.src =
  "myUrl/externalfile.min.js";
s.onload = resolve;
s.onerror = reject;
document.head.appendChild(s);
 });
}
```

In the same file i try to call loadMyScript,
and i would like a new object to be created from the code of my external js :myUrl/externalfile.min.js

```
async function testMethod(button, objet) {
    //new myObjet(button, objet) will be called in myUrl/externalfile.min.js
    return this.loadMyScript().then(() => {
       console.log('Buildin MyObject');
       return new MyObjet(button, objet);
    });
}
```

in my generated html i see this.
Here my method loadMyScript create correctly the html element  in the  :

```
      <script defer="" id="test" src="myUrl/externalfile.min.js"></script>
```

The issue is that the code I wrote in **.then(...)** doesn't seem to be executed => The **MyObject** is not created.

While when I insert the ***<script>*** line manually in the html head, everything seems to work correctly

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding you want to load JavaScript dynamically, from an external file and call a function of that file directly afterwards.

**Why don't you use `import()` for that?**
Instead of appending a script tag to the DOM, you declare your JS file simply as a module and call it inside your current JS file via the `import()` function. It is supported by all major browsers.

1. File to import (e.g. module.js)

```
export function hello() {
  return "Hello, from Module.js";
}
```

2. Your main file (e.g. index.js)

```
import("./path/to/module.js")
.then((module) => {
    console.log(
       module.hello()
    );
    // Do something with the module.
  });
```

You can read a bit more at the [MDN Page for imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports).

Comment: We don't own the external library, is there any other way ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `onload` and `onerror` aren't generally considered "best practice" anymore - you could instead attach event listeners to your created element:

```
function loadMyScript() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.defer = true;
    s.id = "test";
    s.src = "myUrl/externalfile.min.js";
    s.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(s), false);
    s.addEventListener('error', () => reject(s), false);
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't think that this would change the result, doesn't it ?

Comment: @ouzo Why would it not...? Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: first thank you for your help  Esqew, I tried but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run `testMethod`, you are actually returning a `Promise` which means you should use `.then` on it (or `await` if your function is async).

*Take a look at this example where an **external script named `js.js`** is loaded*:

- **Note: in order for this to work you need to have a file `js.js` in the same folder as this snippet (once saved on your local computer)**

```js
function loadMyScript() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let s = document.createElement("script");
        s.src = "js.js";
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    });
};

async function testMethod() {
    return loadMyScript().then(() => func(50), (e) => console.log("Error:", e));
};

function RUN_THIS() {
    testMethod().then(res => {
        if(!res) return;
        alert("Loaded script, executed function. The external function returned: " + res);
    });
};
```

*To make the code more readable, I have used `await` below:*

```js
function loadMyScript() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let s = document.createElement("script");
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject;
        s.src = "js.js";
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    });
};

async function testMethod() {
    const result = await loadMyScript();
    // Now perform checks using "result";
    return func(50);
};

async function RUN_THIS() {
    const result = await testMethod()
    if(!result) return false;
    console.log("Loaded script, executed function. The external function returned:", result);
};
```

Here, `func` is the function or method which is defined in the external script you are trying to load.

Comment: can you explain the meaning of func ?

Comment: @ouzo Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention that, `func` is the function or method which is defined in the external script. `50` is just a random argument I passed just as an example.